# Blackberry, why are links opening in new tabs?

Tags: mobile, blackberry, web, html5boilerplate

I have a pretty plain vanilla site. Demoing for the client, she got out her Blackberry and for some reason when she clicks the navigation links she is always prompted to open the page in a new tab. This didn't happen with other example responsive sites we looked at. What in blazes could I be missing??

If this helps at all, here is what my navigation markup looks like:

```
<nav>
    <a href="/" class="active agenda">Agenda</a>
    <a href="/ask/" class=" ask">Ask?</a>
    <a href="/refer/" class=" refer">Refer</a>
    <a href="/accounts/profile" class=" me">Me</a>
</nav>
```

I am using HTML5BP and the 320 and up framework. No JS is even running on the page. Seriously, what the hell...

Comment: I don't do web development for BlackBerry, so won't be able to help you with the fine details here, but I do know there are huge differences in the BlackBerry browser depending on what OS version is used. OS 5 was the last of the RIM developed browsers.  Starting with OS 6, RIM integrated webkit.  For a question like this, you will need to specify the BlackBerry OS version being tested.  So what BlackBerry is your client using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bold I am familiar with, the 9650, started out with OS 5, but was later upgraded to OS 6.  So it could still be either OS 5 with RIM's terrible browser, or OS 6 with Apple's webkit, depending on whether your client has done an OS upgrade on the device.

RIM's simulators are pretty good for reproducing problems like this, if you don't have a BlackBerry device to test with.  Go to http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/resources/simulators.html and scroll down to the "BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators" section to see all the simulators you can try. The simulators require Windows to run.

Comment: after putting a BlackBerry sim on my VirtualBox instance of Windows, I found it was just some JS gumming up the works.